# Hash and values

Tags: ruby, regex

I came across this `Ruby` script:

```
frequency = Hash.new(0)
...
...
file.read.downcase.scan(/\b[a-z]{4,20}\b/){|word| frequency[word] =
frequency[word]+1}
```

The point I couldn't understand is `frequency[word] = frequency[word]+1`

Wouldn't `frequency[word]` give me the word matched? How can we add it to `1`?

Comment: as a note this would usually be written as `frequency[word] += 1` which will be interpreted as `frequency[word] = frequency[word] +1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`frequency` is defined as a hash with `0` as default value. So when `frequency[word]` is invoked for the `word` that wasn't recorded before it returns 0.

The code seems to count the different words in the text.

When it finishes, the `frequency` will contain words as keys and number of times the particular word appears in the sentence as values.

You can play with it here: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/519da

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What would "frequency[word]" in this case evaluate to? What would it return?

Comment: The issue here is that although I saw how the code runs from rubyfiddle.com, the issue is that I'm not able to digest the value returned by "frequency[word]". If you clarify that, will be very much appreciated.

Comment: `frequency[word]` returns something previously associated with value of the word or 0. For example, `frequency["fox"]` is `0`, then I add 1 to it: `frequency["fox"]+=1` and now `frequency["fox"]` is `1`.

Comment: For instance, we have the word "quick". Why was it given the value "1" while it is not associated with any value? Sorry for my many questions, but, a bit confused in analyzing the way the program is working. Thanks

Comment: Oh, yes, got it now. Your example made it more clear